# Lignting message Channel, publish message onload

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

I have two LWC that talk one to the other, and the behaviour is quite simple;
The first component contain three picklist, the second one will display the ID of the selected picklist item

The picklist have default values and change when the user use the picklist
I managed to send to the message channed when the user change the picklist value but I did not get to have the default value send the message ...

Any idea on how to send the message when the LWC load and after the selected value has been defined

Demo:
[image]

Code:

```
import { LightningElement,wire} from 'lwc';
import getRegion from '@salesforce/apex/PicklistHelper.getRegion';
import getCountry from '@salesforce/apex/PicklistHelper.getCountry';
import getMarket from '@salesforce/apex/PicklistHelper.getMarket';
import {publish, MessageContext} from 'lightning/messageService';
import RegionmessageChannel from '@salesforce/messageChannel/MarketMC__c';


export default class FilterPanel extends LightningElement {
    regionOptionsList;
    countryOptionsList;
    marketOptionsList;
    selectedCountry;
    selectedRegion;
    selectedMarket;


messageContext;

@wire(MessageContext)
messageContextWired(value) {
    this.messageContext = value;
    if (this.messageContext && !this.publishedBefore) {
        this.publishedBefore = true;
        this.sendToother();
    }
}

@wire(getRegion)
retrieveRegion({error, data}){
    let tempArray = []
    let tempDefaultValueList = []
    if(data){
        for(let key in data){
            tempArray.push({label:data[key], value:key}); 
            tempDefaultValueList.push(key);
        }
    }
    this.regionOptionsList = tempArray;
    this.selectedRegion = tempDefaultValueList[0];

}

//connectedCallback() {
//    const payload = { regionID: this.selectedRegion, countryID: this.selectedCountry, marketID: this.selectedMarket};
//    publish(this.messageContext, RegionmessageChannel, payload);
//}



handleRegionChange(event){
    this.selectedRegion = event.target.value;
    const payload = { regionID: this.selectedRegion, countryID: this.selectedCountry, marketID: this.selectedMarket};
    publish(this.messageContext, RegionmessageChannel, payload);
}


@wire(getCountry, {RegionId: '$selectedRegion'})
retrieveCountry({error, data}){
    let CountrytempArray = []
    let countryTempDefaultList = []
    if(data){
        for(let key in data){
            CountrytempArray.push({label:data[key], value:key}); 
            countryTempDefaultList.push(key);
            
        }
    }
    this.countryOptionsList = CountrytempArray;
    this.selectedCountry = countryTempDefaultList[0]
}

handleCountryChange(event){
    this.selectedCountry = event.target.value;
    const payload = {regionID: this.selectedRegion, countryID: this.selectedCountry, marketID: this.selectedMarket};
    publish(this.messageContext, RegionmessageChannel, payload);
}

@wire(getMarket, {CountryId: '$selectedCountry'})
retrieveMarket({error, data}){
    let MarketempArray = []
    let marketTempDefaultList = []
    if(data){
        for(let key in data){
            MarketempArray.push({label:data[key], value:key}); 
            marketTempDefaultList.push(key);
            
        }
    }
    this.marketOptionsList = MarketempArray;
    this.selectedMarket = marketTempDefaultList[0]
}

handleMarketChange(event){
    this.selectedMarket = event.target.value;
    const payload = { regionID: this.selectedRegion, countryID: this.selectedCountry, marketID: this.selectedMarket};
    publish(this.messageContext, RegionmessageChannel, payload);
}
```

}
error message:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't publish the messages until the `messageContext` is loaded using a wired adapter.
So you need to handle that in the wired function of the `messageContext`. Also I have added a flag `publishedBefore` to avoid it publishing multiple times.

```
messageContext;

@wire(MessageContext)
messageContextWired(value) {
    this.messageContext = value;
    if (this.messageContext && !this.publishedBefore) {
        this.publishedBefore = true;
        this.sendToother();
    }
}
```

And you don't need to call that in `connectedCallback()`

Comment: thx for your answer, but when I run the component it output a script errior :[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.

where do you define publishedBefore ? why do you need this.messageContext = value;

Comment: We dont need to define `publishedBefore`, and yes we need `this.messageContext = value;`. can you check on which line you are getting that error?

Comment: I added the error in the description, thx you